# XMLQuery with Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, xquery

I'm doing examples from workbook. I created table and insert couple of records. Below is my code:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_Pracownicy
(IDPracownika NUMBER(3),
Dane XMLTYPE);
```

Insert record to the table:

```
INSERT INTO test_Pracownicy (IDPracownika, Dane)
VALUES (1,
  XMLTYPE('
    <PRecord>
      <Nazwisko>Kowalski</Nazwisko>
      <Imie>Jan</Imie>
      <RokUrodz>1980</RokUrodz>
      <Wzrost>1.77</Wzrost>
      <DataZatr>2001/02/10</DataZatr>
    </PRecord>')
);
```

Now I want to run XMLQuery:

```
SELECT IDPracownika,
  XMLQuery(
    'FOR $i IN /PRecord
      WHERE $i /Nazwisko = "Kowalski"
      ORDER BY $i/Imie
      RETURN $i'
    PASSING by VALUE Dane
    RETURNING CONTENT) NazwiskoXML
FROM test_Pracownicy;
```

and I'm getting error:

```
ORA-19114: XPST0003 - error during parsing the XQuery expression: 
LPX-00801: XQuery syntax error at 'i'
1   FOR $i IN /PRecord
-       ^
19114. 00000 -  "error during parsing the XQuery expression: %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred during the parsing of the XQuery expression.
*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.
Error at Line: 117 Column: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed query to small (for, where, return...) letters and it's workging:

```
SELECT IDPracownika,
  XMLQuery(
    'for $i in /PRecord
      where$i /Nazwisko = "Kowalski"
      order by $i /Imie
      retrun $i'
    PASSING by VALUE Dane
    RETURNING CONTENT) NazwiskoXML
FROM test_Pracownicy;
```

**It's case sensitive.**